# Differences between JSX syntax and React.createElement()

Tags: reactjs, react-router, jsx

I'm having a look at [React Boilerplate](https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate) and I noticed that when I change the syntax from JSX to regular JS (using `React.createElement`) I have the warning `Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop`. So I guess JSX does some extra stuff.
What are the real differences?
Is it possible to fix this warning without using JSX or without providing a key?

Just for clarity, this is the snippet that gives me the warning:

```
React.createElement(AppWrapper, {}, [
  React.createElement(Helmet, {titleTemplate: "Boilerplate"},
    React.createElement('meta', {name: "description"})
  ),
  React.createElement(Switch, {}, [
    React.createElement(Route, {exact: true, path: "/", component: HomePage}),
    React.createElement(Route, {path: "/features", component: FeaturePage}),
  ]),
  React.createElement(Footer)
])
```

And this is the JSX that does not give me any warning:

```
<AppWrapper>
  <Helmet titleTemplate="Boilerplate">
    <meta name="description" />
  </Helmet>
  <Header />
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
    <Route path="/features" component={FeaturePage} />
  </Switch>
  <Footer />
</AppWrapper>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very simple. When you pass just one element as children of another element, that should not be an array.

```
React.createElement(AppWrapper, {}, 
  React.createElement(Helmet, {titleTemplate: "Boilerplate"},
    React.createElement('meta', {name: "description"})
  ),
  React.createElement(Switch, {},
    React.createElement(Route, {exact: true, path: "/", component: HomePage}),
  ),
  React.createElement(Footer)
)
```

Otherwise is like you did in JSX

```
<Helmet titleTemplate="Boilerplate">
   {['description'].map(description => <meta name={description} />)}
</Helmet>
```

And this requires a `key` as well

Comment: Thanks for the answer... I updated the question but the problem is the same: the JSX version does not require to use a key while the JS version still gives the "key" warning.

Comment: You have fixed just one place. You have other two arrays in your first snippet.

Comment: So why is not asking the key in the JSX version as well? Isn't that the same?

Comment: In JSX you use no arrays. It's just one element inside the other element. Like I did in my first snippet.

Comment: You are comparing two difference things basically

Answer (score 0):

If you are rendering array elements react is always asking to provide keys for them. Check this [doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) for more info about rendering list of elements